# Fix responsive SVG breaking out of Bootstrap grid?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, twitter-bootstrap-3

Example Codepen: http://codepen.io/mattrice/full/peXeqd/

What I want is for the SVG to stay completely contained within the parent's given width (6 columns for this example, but could be any other arbitrary width grid element).

This example functions as expected at widths <768px because the Bootstrap columns are full-page width; however, when the Bootstrap columns flow back to horizontally stacked at widths above 768 the SVG takes up the entire width of the page.

I think the problem stems from the arguments to `updateDimensions()` in `render()`:

```
 function render() {
    updateDimensions(window.innerWidth);

    ...<snip>...
  }
```

I have also tried `getBoundingClientRect()` like so

```
 function render() {
    updateDimensions(d3.select(options.selector).node().getBoundingClientRect().width);

    ...<snip>...
  }
```

but that led to some odd results (probably outside of the scope of this question).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the SVG to scale to fit its parent element, it needs to have a `viewBox` attribute.

Instead of setting the `width` and `height` of your SVG, use those values for the `viewBox` instead.

Change

```
.attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
```

to

```
.attr("viewBox", [0, 0, (width + margin.right + margin.left),
                        (height + margin.top + margin.bottom)].join(' '))
```

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWjZMg)

You may want to tweak the width and height components of the `viewBox` if you want, to remove the gap on the right, so it fits more neatly.